# Excel sumif returns big number instead of zero

Tags: excel

I have a column of positive and negative numbers, which when summed should balance to zero (it's an accounting sheet).

However, if I use a SUMIF formula, instead of 0, i get:
1.81899E-12 or -9.09495E-13 or similar. (I don't know what this sort of result is called, but I think they represent very large or very small numbers)

I have created a sample document which shows the issue.

It returns a zero if the cell is formatted as a number, but the above result if formatted as general.

I often also find that even the simple SUM function also returns a similar result, as does the SUM in the status bar at the bottom of excel, so it is not just the SUMIF function I am struggling with. However, I have been unable to recreate the issue with the SUM function in my example spreadsheet.

I'm using Excel as part of Home and Business 2013.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Numbers like `xxxE-12` or `xxxE-13` are very small, not very large. Possibly you are dealing with rounding errors, while you expect to have value `0`.

Comment: Try adding a filter to the column of numbers and then checking the drop-down which will be sorted smallest to largest - any of the numbers look odd? Any of the numbers appear in the wrong order (indicating that Excel is treating them as text.

Comment: Thanks, I have filtered the columns and there are no strange numbers. The numbers range from -29632.63000 to 12632.47000 and all are rounded to two decimal points. the numbers nearest to zero are -1182.69000 and 10.0000.

Comment: Weirdly, filtering the columns has elicitated another strange result. If the order of the columns is altered, then the sumif result changes (still has the very small number, but it changes from 1.81899E-12 to 3.63798E-12. Why would the order of the column affect the sumif result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Dominique pointed out, `xxxE-12` is a *very, very* small number. It is very, very close to zero.

`xxxE-12` is Excel's (and most programming languages') way of writing `xxx * 10^-12`.

As you guessed, this is due to rounding. It however also displays the issues of how computers handles floating-point (decimal) numbers; what you think is 1 / 3 = 0.333 might be represented internally as something like 0.333333681. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic, or notably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems.

Secondly, why this appears if the cell is formatted as "General", but not "Number"? With "Number", you expect an integer part and at most, say, 3 decimals. `x.xxE-12` has the largest non-zero component at the 12th (!) decimal. So when displayed, it gets rounded to a nice zero. "General" however attempts to display the number as close to the actual value, which in this case is the `xxxE-12`.

Also note that this might give you issues if you try to compare your calculated value with zero. Say, `=IF(SUMIF(...) = 0, ...`; it might not evaluate to TRUE even when you think it does (due to the very small value). The solution is instead to compare the difference of calculated value to zero: `=IF(ABS(SUMIF(...) - 0) < 1E-9, ...`.

Comment: Thanks, however I am still confused. I suspected that rounding may be an issue, so i rounded all of the numbers to two decimal places and replaced them with the values of the rounded results. I still get the same error. Can I post the example book somehow for people to see?

Comment: I should clarify - I suspected that rounding was the error before I posted my question on Stackoverflow, so I am confident that this is not the problem, because the numbers have been rounded using ROUND(xx,2) and then the results copied and pasted as values over the originals. The originals and the rounded results look identical when formatted to 5 decimal places (ie nothing after the 2nd decimal place).

Comment: I have also tried manually overtyping each number in the column with its decimal, to ensure that the number only has 2 decimal places.

Comment: Also, if I create a for and if loop in VBA and do the sums that way, it returns zero.

Comment: Please read the link on floating-point arithmetic. Even if you are inputting numbers strictly rounded to 2 decimals, the internal representation of the number is not. Excel would still be operating on some binary representation of that number, where the order of addition may have an impact. That your VBA code returns a different result may be due to it using a different datatype (single vs. double).

Comment: Thank you, I see your point. If I change the number format to 50 decimal places, I can see that Excel is not reading 0, but 0.0000000000000023845321100000 (or something). I have a workaround in VBA now and will explore your ABS() solution as well.